# How to hide "do something on load"

Tags: 7, entities, status-messages

I am using drupal 7 with custom omega theme. I am developing a site for myself for a year now. I could find a solution to everything until now. Hopefully the answer is easy and simple I just don't see the wood from the tree.

How can I remove or hide the 'Do something on load' message, but keeping those messages what I want to appear?

Thank you for your time to read, and I'm hoping in a quick and good response

Thank you everyone who looked at it.
It seems I have found the answer.
Yes it really is connected to the Entity Reference field.
There is a sub-module called " Entity Reference Behavior Example".
All I needed to do is to disable this sub module.
I have fallen into that mistake to switch it on without knowing exactly what it is doing.
Simply switch it OFF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen that message myself yet, but just came across a suggestion how to avoid that message. I suppose you're using the entityreference module? At least for what I know the message seems to come from there – so hopefully this hint helps you:

> To avoid some status messages like 'Do something on load', you should uncheck "Test behavior" in "Additional behaviors" section.

As far as I know the author is relating to the entityreference settings – here's the source: "[how to render a node field of a referenced node on the node form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89424/how-to-render-a-node-field-of-a-referenced-node-on-the-node-form)". I hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have seen this suggestion already, however I couldn't find that additional behaviors section yet. I will do a closer look at that module, hopefully will be there.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply disable the "Entity Reference Behavior Example" module.